# Shorthand syntax for generic interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, .net

`T?` is shorthand for `Nullable<T>` Eg: `int?` is shorthand for `Nullable<int>`
Is shorthand syntax a part of the language specification?

Are we allowed to create our own shorthand syntax for generic interfaces?

Comment: Thank you for the concise answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `?` is part of specification. You cannot create your own shortcuts like that.

> **4.1.10 Nullable types**
>
> A nullable type can represent all values of its underlying type plus
>   an additional `null` value. A nullable type is written `T?`, where `T` is
>   the underlying type. This syntax is shorthand for `System.Nullable<T>`,
>   and the two forms can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicions. The shorthand made the nullable types easier to adopt. I was hoping to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable is defined within the [C# specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (near the end of section 1.3). There is no way to do something like this yourself.

> Nullable types also do not have to be declared before they can be used. For each non-nullable value type T there is a corresponding
>   nullable type T?, which can hold an additional value null. For
>   instance, int? is a type that can hold any 32 bit integer or the value
>   null.